# Close or hide Inputpane on Tap or click of listviewItem

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have been working on a Windows 8 App and I've run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out.  My app is using an MVVM design pattern and I would like there to be as little Code behind throughout my app as possible.

The problem I'm having is I have a Listview with a variety of items.  These item are templated to have Textbox's within them so you can edit an item's description.  When a user clicks on te textbox within the listiewItem the touch keyboard displays, however when the user is finished and say touched another listviewItem but not necessarily the textbox. The Keyboard stays up.

So it goes as follows.  User taps textbox in listviewItem and Keyboard pops up.  User is done so the user taps the another listviewItem but not the textbox.  Keyboard stays up.  This is not desired.

I would like to have the Keyboard close or hide when the user touches anything other than a textbox.

I have read the white paper on the Input pane [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx) and I understand the logic but unfortunately it's not desirable for my business case.

I have linked a [Sample Project](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=F916D7BE726A1FA1&id=F916D7BE726A1FA1!107) that will produce what I'm talking about above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your specific requirements there are various solutions I can think off. I looked at the Sample Project you provided.

- My first solution would be to swap the ListView for an ItemsControl. In the sample you are not using the SelectedItem, so putting an ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer would work as well. Since you wouldn't be dealing with a ListItem anymore it would prevent the InputPane from staying up.
- If you do require a ListView you can handle the change in SelectedItem to shift focus. Put an invisible element behind your interface (not being a TextBox obviously) and give it focus if something other than the TextBlock is selected. You could use a ListViewStyle that doesn't show anything for a selected item if you don't want it showing up in your interface.

Please let me know if any of these solutions would be suitable for your scenario. I can provide some sample code if required.

Comment: I ended up using an ItemsControl as you mentioned and it worked great :).  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!